# How to compute the hourly average of a value in SQL?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I am working with `pyspark` and I would like to run a `spark.sql` query to compute the hourly average of some values.

I have a table like the following

```
ID            timestamp                val
A        2020-01-19 03:03:00            5
A        2020-01-19 03:33:00            3
A        2020-01-19 03:55:00            7
A        2020-01-20 05:44:00            6 
A        2020-01-20 05:54:00            4 
B        2020-01-19 02:15:00            1
B        2020-01-19 02:22:00            0
B        2020-01-19 06:15:00            9
B        2020-01-19 06:44:00            2
```

I would like a table like the following

```
ID              time                  avgval
A        2020-01-19 03:00:00            5
A        2020-01-20 05:00:00            5
B        2020-01-19 02:00:00            1
B        2020-01-19 06:00:00            5.5
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle,SQL Server, MySQL etc.,?

Comment: I tried to explain the environment in which I work

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by a simple `group by` query with `date_format` function.

```
spark.sql(
    """
       SELECT ID
            , date_format(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00') as time
            , mean(val) as avgval
         FROM table 
        GROUP BY ID
               , date_format(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00')
        ORDER BY ID
               , date_format(timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:00:00')
    """) \
.show(20, False)
```

The result is:

```
+---+-------------------+------+
|ID |time               |avgval|
+---+-------------------+------+
|A  |2020-01-19 03:00:00|5.0   |
|A  |2020-01-20 05:00:00|5.0   |
|B  |2020-01-19 02:00:00|0.5   |
|B  |2020-01-19 06:00:00|5.5   |
+---+-------------------+------+
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you use `date_trunc()`:

```
select id, date_trunc('hour', time) as yyyymmddhh,
       avg(val)
from t
group by id, date_trunc('hour', time);
```